How to determin the theoretical prediction limit for a complex process?
how can we find out what is the theoretical prediction limit for a complex process?
For example, for a coin toss (on average) the prediction limit is 50%, that is we cannot predict better than this maximum, practically speaking (unless we have access to "insider information" like initial conditions etc)
For a complex process, are there any tools we can use to determine that theoretical prediction maximum, beyond which we cannot predict?
So I am not very happy of the wording of the above question (apologies) but I did ask GPT4 and the answer might help understand the question a bit better:

Determining the theoretical prediction limit for a complex process is
a challenging task that involves understanding the inherent
uncertainty and unpredictability of the process. There are several
tools and concepts from various fields such as information theory,
chaos theory, and statistical mechanics that can help in assessing
this limit. Here are some of the key approaches and tools:

Shannon Entropy (Information Theory)...
Kolmogorov Complexity (Algorithmic Information Theory)...
etc etc


The reason why I am interested is from a ML point of view. First it can help with determining:

overfitting (yes I am aware that there are other practical methods to determine this but in this prediction limit it might be more challenging)
data leak (these things can be a bit more difficult to determine especially for time-series data)
maximum theoretical performance of a model, close to which you are starting approaching the Pareto principle of effort vs reward.

So imagine such a complex process (for argument's sake) is prediction of sporting events or a political voting outcome.
